# Field from table not showing correctly after INNER JOIN - Undefined index

Tags: php, mysql

Well, I've been trying to deal with this problem the whole afternoon/evening, and I know I'm close... still can't get it right :/

I have a database (created with phpMyAdmin as I'm learning to use it), it has subjects and careers, and fields like id, name, description, etc.

Table Subjects has an id AND a foreign key from table Careers (the id for Careers). I've done that in phpMyAdmin using the relation view.

Then... I have a main php file for the main page (like a "home"), and in there I've included a link to another php file which shows the table with all the subjects (Name of the subject, Description, Hours, Career, and Actions)

This is the table part in the Home.php:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover tabla">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="thead_texto">Subject</th>
                        <th class="thead_texto">Description</th>
                        <th class="thead_texto">Hours</th>
                        <th class="thead_texto">Carrer</th>
                        <th class="thead_texto">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody><!-- Loop for the subjects -->
                    <?php
                      include("../extras/tablaSubjects.php");
                    ?>
                </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is the php file that deals with showing the subjects and informations from the database:

```
<!-- This comes from another file that have the info for the conection -->
<?php
    include("conexion.php");

//Conection
$CONN = new mysqli($serverName, $username, $password, $dataBase);

//Checking
if ($CONN->connect_error){
    echo("Error de conexion");
}
else{
    echo "Conectado";
}

//Showing the subjects and information

//Query to select
$SQL = "SELECT s.id, s.name, s.description, s.hours, c.name FROM subjects m JOIN careers c ON (s.career_id = c.id)";
$resultado = $CONN->query($SQL);

//Part of the tbody where the loop will be
if($result->num_rows > 0){
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<tr>";  
        echo "<td>{$row['s.name']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row['description']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row['hours']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row['name']}</td>";
        echo '<td><a class="btn btn-primary" value="'.$row['id'].'">Edit</a>    <a class="btn btn-danger" value="'.$row['id'].'">Delete</a> </td>';
    echo "</tr>"; 
}
}else{
echo "<tr><td>No data<td></tr>";
}
?>
```

It actually works fine... except when trying to show the name of the SUBJECTS :/
In this part:

```
echo "<td>{$row['s.name']}</td>"; --> this gives an error, "Undefined index"
        echo "<td>{$row['description']}</td>";  --> OK, info from SUBJECT
        echo "<td>{$row['hours']}</td>"; --> OK, info from SUBJECT
        echo "<td>{$row['name']}</td>";  --> This displays the name of the CAREER :/
```

I can't seem to understand WHY it displays all the data from SUBJECT and even the name of the CAREER but not the name of the SUBJECT :/
If I write name on it, it still displays the name of the career.
If I write "subject.name", still says "Undefined index"

Comment: What does this have to do with the PhpMyAdmin application? You have your own PHP script, you're not using that tool.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `subjects s` instead of `subjects m`?

Comment: @Barmar Hi! Yes, the thing is that I've translated the whole thing so people understand it haha I'm actually using Spanish, so "subjects" is "materias", and so was using the m. I forgot to change it here xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table prefix isn't included in the keys of the associative array returned by `fetch_assoc()`, they just have the column names. So if you select both `s.name` and `c.name`, there will just be one `$row['name']`, which contains the last one in the `SELECT` list.

To get both, you should give one of them an alias.

```
$SQL = "SELECT s.id, s.name, s.description, s.hours, c.name AS career_name FROM subjects s JOIN careers c ON (s.career_id = c.id)";
```

Then you can use `$row['name']` for `s.name` and `$row['career_name']` for `c.name`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! This worked like a charm! :D I knew I was close hahaha! I've voted this but won't change publicly because I don't have enough reputation. I also accepted this as the answer as it's the approach I've used :D

Answer (score 0):

You have two `name`s in your `select`.  The period and the table name before it is discarded.  So, do something like this:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name as s_name, s.description, s.hours, c.name
```

Then you can look for `s_name` in the result set rather than `s.name`.

If you really, really want `s.name`, you can do that as well:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name as `s.name`, s.description, s.hours, c.name
```

Note that you need the backticks, because periods are not usually allowed in identifiers.

Comment: @gordon-lindoff Hi! Thanks for this, I've voted this answer but will not publicly change because I don't have enough reputation.